# Can any one tell API to add bulb Phillips Hue Bridges?

Tags: ios, philips-hue

I have worked on Phillips iOS SDK, now i want to use phillips APIs ,
Is there any API to add bulb to hue bridge?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Philips has no api for adding a bulb.
Please refer http://www.developers.meethue.com/

Answer (score 3):

The Philips hue API has an API call to search for new lights (bulbs). A description of the API call that does this can be found here:

http://www.developers.meethue.com/documentation/lights-api#13_search_for_new_lights

(Please note that the website can only be viewed after you have registered for a developer account.)

Answer (score -2):

If you are ok with replacing the hue bridge with Raspberry Pi, you can also try [kappa.io](http://kappa.io). It contains API's to control Philips Hue bulbs and all other ZHA/ZLL bulbs.

You can give a quick try by using the pre-built images, which out-of-box allows you to do things such as changing color, brightness, on/off, add, delete. It also let you factory reset the bulbs.